# Import Antd css inside react component

Tags: reactjs, antd

when using antd's css why not import according to the syntax import "node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css" but import this way import "antd/dist/antd.css"
Thanks all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement syntax is like this:

```
import "module-name"
```

So, it's already use node_modules as base path.

Have a look at Mozilla JavaScript Reference link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

"The module to import from. This is often a relative or absolute path name to the .js file containing the module. Certain bundlers may permit or require the use of the extension; check your environment. Only single quoted and double quoted Strings are allowed."

Comment: You can the import CSS path in main file , it will solve your problem or <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.16.13/antd.min.js" integrity="sha512-igKMRCoX5qNcJSpEEXR0Tw7DfxYyWgPntklgv5TES1VLx+kX9FMmqTmm/O/518t8ARYgoAXaQioGvgNMJs9GgA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script> add this CDN path